# Find the number of conjugacy classes in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I know all the elements of $S_4=\{e,(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34),(12)(34),(13)(24),(12)(23),(123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143),(234),(243),(1234),(1342),(1423),(1243),(1432),(1324)\}$

I also understand that $e, (12), (12)(34), (123)$, and $(1234)$ are the classes.  What's confusing me is how to find the number of elements in each class. For example I see ($12)(12)(12)^{-1}=(12)$ but when we look at the next element we see $(13)(12)(13)^{-1}=((13)(1) (13)(2))$.

How do we simplfy this/ how are we using number theory here to get elements of these classes?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274657/bijection-between-permissible-cycle-types-and-conjugacy-classes

Comment: Answer from J.Schmidt in this post may help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/379912/399263

Comment: Did you learn about cycle types? Each cycle type corresponds to a conjugacy class. This should make the rest of the exercise easy.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $(12)(23)$ in your list of elements is not in disjoint cycle form like the others you listed; perhaps you meant $(14)(23)$